# Showing that $R \otimes_{R[X]} R[Y] \cong R[Y]/(Y^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> **Problem:** Let $R$ be a ring and consider the ring homomorphisms $$ \phi: R[X] \rightarrow R: \sum_{i=0}^n a_i X^{i} \mapsto a_0 $$ and $$
>  \psi : R[X] \rightarrow R[Y] : \sum_{i=0}^n a_i X^{i} \mapsto
>  \sum_{i=0}^n a_i Y^{2i}. $$
>
> a) Explain how these morphisms induce an $R[X]$-module structure on
>   $R$ and on $R[Y]$.
>
> b) Show that $$R \otimes_{R[X]} R[Y] \cong R[Y]/(Y^2). $$

**Attempt:** 
a) Define the action of $R[X]$ on $R$ as $$ R[X] \times R \rightarrow R: (f(X), r) \mapsto a_0 r $$ where $f(X) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i X^{i}. $

Furthermore, define the action of $R[X]$ on $R[Y]$ by $$ R[X] \times R[Y] \rightarrow R[Y] : ( \sum_{i=0}^n a_i X^{i}, \sum_{j=0}^m b_j Y^{j}) \mapsto \left( \sum_{i=0}^n a_i Y^{2i} \right) \left( \sum_{j=0}^m b_j Y^j \right). $$

b) For this part, I was not sure. I first tried to define a map $$ \chi: R \times R[Y] \rightarrow R[Y] / (Y^2) : (r, \sum_{i=0}^n a_i Y^{i}) \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^n ra_i Y^{i} + (Y^2) $$ and I think it is $R[X]$-bilinear, and then use the universal property of tensor product. But I didn't know how to find the inverse of $\chi$.

I also tried to look at an exact sequence of the form $$ 0 \rightarrow (Y^2) \rightarrow R[Y] \rightarrow R[Y] / (Y^2) \rightarrow 0 $$ and then try to tensor with $R$ maybe, but I could not prove the stated isomorphism in this way.

Help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: For any commutative ring $A$ and any ideal $I$ of $A$, there is a natural isomorphism of $A$-modules $A/I \otimes_{A} M \to M/IM$ sending the simple tensor $\overline{x} \otimes M$ to the class of $xm$ in $M/IM$ (where $x \in A$). In your case, $A = R[X], I = \langle X \rangle$. (This is your "tensor with $R$'' idea, more or less.)

Comment: It may be good to have a first intuitive look at the question : $X$ acts as $0$ on $R$ and as multiplication by $Y^2$ on $R[Y]$

Comment: Using Alex Wertheim's, suggestion, I get $R[Y] \otimes_{R[X]} \frac{R[X]}{ (X)} \cong  \frac{ R[Y]}{ (X) R[Y]}. $ How do I show the latter is isomorphic to $R[Y]/(Y^2)$ though? that would give me the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the latter isomorphism in your comment by noting Max's comment. Otherwise, you can proceed as you did before by describing explicitly the isomorphism.

Your attempt in part b is correct, just need to check the $R[X]$-bilinearity of the map which is basically by definition. One comment here is that we should write the map $\chi$ as
$$\chi: R \times R[Y] \rightarrow R[Y] / (Y^2) : (r, \sum_{i=0}^n a_i Y^{i}) \mapsto  r(a_0 +a_1 Y^{1}) + (Y^2)$$
 The inverse of $\chi$ (the tensor product version of $\chi$) is the obvious one, i.e, 
$$\phi: R[Y]/(Y^2) \rightarrow  R \otimes_{R[X]} R[Y] : a_0 +a_1 Y^{1} + (Y^2)\mapsto 1 \otimes (a_0+a_1y) $$

From this, it is clear that the composition map $R[Y]/(Y^2) \rightarrow  R \otimes_{R[X]} R[Y] \rightarrow R[Y] / (Y^2)$ is the identity. In order to check that the map $R \otimes_{R[X]} R[Y] \rightarrow R[Y] / (Y^2) \rightarrow  R \otimes_{R[X]} R[Y]$ is also the identity, notice the following 
\begin{align*}
&\ \ \ \ \ a\otimes (b_0+b_1y+b_2y^2+\ldots +b_{2n}y^{2n}+b_{2n+1}y^{2n+1})\\
&=a\otimes (b_0+b_2y^2+\ldots +b_{2n}y^{2n})+a\otimes (b_1y+b_3y^3+\ldots +b_{2n+1}y^{2n+1})\\
&= a\otimes (b_0+b_2x+\ldots +b_{2n}x^{n}).1+a\otimes (b_1+b_3x+\ldots +b_{2n+1}x^{n}).y\\
&= a.(b_0+b_2x+\ldots +b_{2n}x^{n})\otimes1+a.(b_1+b_3x+\ldots +b_{2n+1}x^{n})\otimes y\\
&= a.b_0\otimes 1 +a.b_1\otimes y\\
&= a \otimes (b_0+b_1y)
\end{align*}
(the $.$ sign is the $R[X]$-multiplication in the modules $R$ and $R[Y]$). Actually this is the reason why we have the isomorphism. I hope this is clear enough.